# How do i retrieve the percentage of fragmentation on my computer disks using c#

Tags: c#, performance, disk

How do i retrieve  the percentage of fragmentation on my computer disks using c#?
What about the memory fragmentation?  I m quite confuse about similarity, is it the same? How can I get it?
I have already taken a look in the DriveInfo class, but i could not get any info about fragmentation...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Defrag API wrappers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx)